# Tensorflow: Use tf.parse_example for jpeg batches

Tags: tensorflow

I just stumbled over this question:
[TensorFlow - Read all examples from a TFRecords at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151895/tensorflow-read-all-examples-from-a-tfrecords-at-once?rq=1)

And the first answer suggest using tf.parse_example instead of parsing single examples because that seems to be faster. But the code provided is not complete and I don't know how I can use that. If I batch and then use parse_example I will get a batch of features. That means I need to unpack that batch in order to decode the jpegs? The code from the answer is:

```
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
 _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
 features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, features={
      image/center': tf.VarLenFeature(tf.string),
  })
 image = features['image/center']
 image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image.values[0], channels=3)
 return image_decoded
```

And suggest switching to:

```
batch = tf.train.batch([serialized_example], num_examples, capacity=num_examples)
parsed_examples = tf.parse_example(batch, feature_spec)
```

But how can I now decode those parsed_examples?

Comment: What does happen when you execute it as-is? According to [tf.decode_raw documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#decode_raw) it should decode the whole batch of examples.

Comment: Ah sorry I copied that code from the other question, not realizing that it's a litte different. I use jpegs... I will edit the question! tf.image.decode_jpeg does not support batches I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. The way I went about it is by using the [higher order operators](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/functional_ops/higher_order_operators) of TensorFlow, `tf.map_fn` to be specific:

```
batch = tf.train.batch([serialized_example], num_examples, capacity=num_examples)

parsed_examples = tf.parse_example(batch, 
    features={
        'image_jpg': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    })

raw_bytes_batch = parsed_examples['image_jpg']

def decode(raw_bytes):
    return tf.image.decode_jpeg(raw_bytes, channels=3)

image_decoded = tf.map_fn(decode, raw_bytes_batch, dtype=tf.uint8,
                          back_prop=False, parallel_iterations=10)
# image_decoded.set_shape([None, ..., ..., 3])
```

This should run the `decode` function on the JPEGs in parallel.